# Eclipse Forcing Me To Name My Project A Specific Name

Tags: java, eclipse

I was looking at my code today and my project was giving me errors so I ended up deleting the thing (It had some code I was done with). Next I went to create a new project my the same name but when I did it gave me the same project with all the old .java files inside. So I went on to trying to make the name in lowercase and eclipse game me this "error" if you would even call it that???
[Stack Overflow said I had to use a link to the image so please don't say "you broke the rules"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOiYt.png).

Comment: The eclipse suggested that name as per the naming convention.Might be this name suggested as per the lint rules configured in the eclipse

Comment: so how would i fix it from doing that

Comment: Please look into it I don't know that much http://wiki.eclipse.org/Development_Resources/HOWTO/Project_Naming_Policy

Comment: But thats weird because it let me name it "Macrodom" Before its only doing this now that I deleted the "MacroDom" project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally whenever one deletes a project in Eclipse it will ask if you want to delete the entire project contents on the disk. Like so:
[Deleting Eclipse project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/345aO.png)

If not, check your projects folder in Eclipse via Finder to make sure that entire folder is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your workspace location in eclipse or move the old project to other location from your location. Hope this will fix your problem